# How can I use variables in useEffect without having them in a dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have an objectList and a size variable.

```
const [objectList, setObjectList] = useState([]); //will be filled elsewhere
const [size, setSize] = useState([props.width, props.height]); //might change on user input

useEffect(() => {
    //When size changes iterate over objectList
    objectList.forEach(object => {
        object.set({
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height
        );
    });
}, [size]);
```

Here React complains, that objectList is not in dependency, because it might be, that I want to depend the useEffect on objectList changes. However I don't. Objects can be added to the list occasionally but in this case I am setting size where the object will be added to the list. I do not want to iterate over every object when I add a new object to the list (objectList changed), only when the size changed.

How can I iterate over the objectList on each size change but not on objectList change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two actions affecting the `objectList`: on size change and when new object is added.You **need** to separate these two.

You can achieve this via [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to manage the different actions.

```
const initialState = {
  objectList: []
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_OBJECT': /* TODO */ return;
    case 'UPDATE_SIZE': {
       const { size } = action.payload;
       return state.objectList.map((o) => ({
         ...o,
         width: size.width,
         height: size.height
       }))
    }
    default: /* TODO */;
  }
}

function App(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_SIZE',
      payload: {
        size: {
          width: props.width,
          height: props.height
        }
      }
    });
  }, [props.size]);
}
```

Comment: Hm, if I had an onSizeChanged function, I could iterate over the objectList anyhow even without using a reducer, not? But that wouldn't work when I wanted it in a useEffect function.

Comment: I just saw your recent update about `props.width`, etc.  Updated. Anyway, it's an anti-pattern where you use `props.width`, etc as initial state if the parent and child component updates these props too.

Comment: Ok this would be possible however is there an alternative? I am not using useReducer in my app. It would require quite a refactoring effort to change the whole app to useReducer. I extracted the example more abstract because I can't post the whole app code here.

Comment: Well, the only difference is how to update `objectList` which is dispatching an action rather than via `setObjectList ` and accessing the `objectList` is just adding `state` like `state.objectList`. I don't think it's too much refactor given only two actions affecting `objectList`. If it is, I smell something else.

Comment: I realize that useReducer is probably best practice here and I always wanted to refactor to useReducer, however I wanted to add this feature quickly, the app needs quite some rework as I am writing it while learning. It works like it is now and refactor is needed but the time is limited now. That's why I wanted  to see if I can just use useEffect here. I have a workaround now, that I get the objectList locally into a `const objects` but will come back to your answer when I have time to cleanup and refactor everything. Hence I check the answer as accepted correct.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this and it worked.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setObjectList((objectList)=>{
        objectList.forEach(object => {
            object.set({
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height
            );
        });
    
        return objectList;
    });
}, [size]);
```